# req.body automatically cast array to object after 20 entries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my form I can add as many properties as I want dynamically:

```
<form action="">
  <div class="property">
    <label>Name : <input type="text" name="properties[1][name]"></label>
    <label>Order : <input type="text" name="properties[1][order]"></label>
    <label>Label : <input type="text" name="properties[1][label]"></label>
    <label>Type : <input type="text" name="properties[1][type]"></label>
    <label>Description : <textarea name="properties[1][description]"></textarea></label>
  </div>
  <div class="property">
    <label>Name : <input type="text" name="properties[2][name]"></label>
    <label>Order : <input type="text" name="properties[2][order]"></label>
    <label>Label : <input type="text" name="properties[2][label]"></label>
    <label>Type : <input type="text" name="properties[2][type]"></label>
    <label>Description : <textarea name="properties[2][description]"></textarea></label>
  </div>
  <div class="property">
    <label>Name : <input type="text" name="properties[3][name]"></label>
    <label>Order : <input type="text" name="properties[3][order]"></label>
    <label>Label : <input type="text" name="properties[3][label]"></label>
    <label>Type : <input type="text" name="properties[3][type]"></label>
    <label>Description : <textarea name="properties[3][description]"></textarea></label>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

In node.js, I want to do a `forEach` on `req.body.properties` but with more than 20 properties, `req.body.properties` is somehow cast in `Object` and `forEach` function does not exist anymore.

```
propUpdate: (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body;
  console.log('isArray :', Array.isArray(post.properties));
  console.log('isObject :', require('lodash').isObject(post.properties));
  console.log('properties :', post.properties);
...
}
```

Here is the result with 20 properties or less :

```
isArray : true
isObject : true
properties : [ { name: 'test 1',
    order: '1',
    label: 'label 1',
    type: 'type 1' },
  { name: 'test 2',
    order: '2',
    label: 'label 2',
    type: 'type 2' },
....
  { name: 'test 20',
    order: '20',
    label: 'label 20',
    type: 'type 20' } ]
```

And with more than 20 properties :

```
isArray : false
isObject : true
properties : { '1' :
  { name: 'test 1',
    order: '1',
    label: 'label 1',
    type: 'type 1' },
  '2' :
  { name: 'test 2',
    order: '2',
    label: 'label 2',
    type: 'type 2' },
....
  '21' :
  { name: 'test 21',
    order: '21',
    label: 'label 21',
    type: 'type 21' } }
```

I would like to understand why node.js have this behavior and how avoid it.
Is anyone can help me ?

PS : I had to reduce my code example because stackoverflow does not like having more code than explanation. Hope this is still understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body-parser` (which handles request bodies) uses the [`qs`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library to parse URL-encoded data.

The [documentation](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#parsing-arrays) for that library states, about arrays:

> **qs** will also limit specifying indices in an array to a maximum index of 20. Any array members with an index of greater than 20 will instead be converted to an object with the index as the key
>
> ...
>
> This limit can be overridden by passing an `arrayLimit` option

However, there doesn't seem to be a way of passing that option to `qs` through `body-parser`. But it's relatively easy to convert the object to an array:

```
post.properties.length = Object.keys(post.properties).length;
let properties = Array.from(post.properties);
```

Comment: I converted it already, but it irritated me not to understand why it behaved like that. And I didn't know `Array.from` either. Thank you for that too.